# 'Proxy' is undefined in IE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cross-browser, umijs

I have built an Excel add-in by React+Node+[Umi](https://umijs.org/). We have implemented our authentication system. The authentication works in Chrome and Safari, I just realized that it does not work well in IE11; `F12` shows that `'Proxy' is undefined`.

Although it is an Excel add-in, we could reproduce the error (and the same error message) just in browser. Open the link https://jsaddin.10studio.tech/welcome/?next=formulaEditor in IE 11, sign in with ID `3094557608@qq.com` and password: `123456`. We could see the error message in F12.

[image]

Does anyone know

1. how to fix this?
2. how could I know which library/part of my code uses this `Proxy`? I may replace it by alternatives.

**Edit 1:** In `.umirc.ts`:

```
treeShaking: true,
targets: {
  ie: 9,
  safari: 9,
},
```

In `package.json`:

```
"umi": "^2.7.0",
"umi-plugin-react": "^1.8.0",
"umi-types": "^0.2.0"
```

**Edit 2:**

I tried `yarn add proxy-polyfill`, then `yarn start`. Curiously, it raised an error in localhost `Invalid character` and `'umi' is undefined`:

[image]

Comment: hi, i am also facing same issue, 'Proxy' is undefined. i have added import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11"; but still same issue. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a polyfill. Did you check this config for umi.js? https://umijs.org/config/#targets

Setting the target of ie to 11 (as in the above link) should handle adding the polyfills you need.

```
  targets: {
    ie: 11,
    ...other browsers
  },
  ...rest of the config
```

LE:

In case there is an issue with umi.js you can try adding the needed polyfills yourself (e.g. here is one for Proxy https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill)

Comment: It is currently `ie: 9` in `.umirc.ts`. As it is `Configuring the minimum version of browsers you want to compatible with`, it should be compatible with IE 11, right?

Comment: @SoftTimur looks like there is an open issue about this in the Github repo of umi.js https://github.com/umijs/umi/issues/3985. I would suggest adding the polyfill yourself until the issue is resolved

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know that. Did you try adding the needed polyfill by yourself?

Comment: I have not tried yet. I'm still trying to test the project on my local windows. Based on the readme, I should first `Install via your favourite package manager as proxy-polyfill`, then what does `You should include proxy-polyfill into your build system (just require it directly, it doesn't export anything), or import the proxy.min.js file directly. ` mean?

Comment: you can just do `require('proxy-polyfill')` somewhere at the root of your project (do you have an index.js file where you mount react?), after installing the package (do you use npm?)

Comment: Or you can add the proxy.min.js inside node_modules to your html file, before other scripts are included. I'm not exactly sure of your setup, so I cannot say exactly how to include this file, you just need to put it somewhere in your project

Comment: @SoftTimur also, I see you are using umi@2.7, can you try upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: @SoftTimur any news on this? did you try adding the polyfill yourself?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I have not tried yet. I will let you know...

Comment: Please see my `Edit 2` in OP.

Comment: I see, does the error happen in other browsers as well or only IE?

Comment: can you try setting the target for ie to 11 instead of 9? and for safari to 10?