# How can we publish an office add-in that does not support IE?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

We plan to publish a new Office add-in to Microsoft AppSource.

Currently, this new add-in works with Edge, but does not work with IE. Is it still possible to publish it?

During the publishing process, where should we specify that it does not support IE?

Comment: You can find the list of browsers that are expected to be supported at this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#11203-functionality

Comment: May I know the reason that the add-in do not support IE?

Comment: @RaymondLu Here is for example what blocks us now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348709/proxy-is-undefined-in-ie

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms Cheers, so it seems that we must support IE.